# Will apt-get dist-upgrade blow away my PostgreSQL server setup?

Tags: server, upgrade, apt, postgresql

I'm about to upgrade my webserver, my site relies heavily on PostgreSQL database and settings.  I started apt-get dist-upgrade, and it says it wants to upgrade Postgres.  I cancelled, but will it wipe out my database and settings?  I know, "backup" and I have, but I still prefer not to set it up again if I can avoid it.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between `apt-get dist-upgrade` and upgrading from one version of Ubuntu to another, they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

No, it shouldn't overwrite any databases. As for the settings, the new package may have updated settings files (eg. for a new default value or a completely new setting) but it should always ask you for a confirmation about overwriting the settings. That dialogue will also have an option to compare the new and old settings file and an option to keep the old settings. Since you have a backup, it is safe to install the update.

Answer (score 1):

It will not wipe out your database or settings.

But there is a chance that you will run into Debian bug [#714725](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=714725), which will cause your old server package to be uninstalled, leaving you unable to access your data.  For example, if you now have `postgresql-8.4` installed and the upgrade proposes to install `postgresql-9.1`, the old 8.4 instance should just keep on running.  But it's possible that `apt-get dist-upgrade` decides to uninstall the `postgresql-8.4` package, which wouldn't be good.  So be sure to read the output of `apt-get dist-upgrade` about what it proposes to do.  If you don't like what it proposes to remove, run something like `apt-get install postgresql-8.4` to mark the package(s) as manually installed.